# Is there any way to bypass recaptcha verification when using PhoneAuth in Firebase with paying for Google Cloud Console

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-play-integrity-api

I am using OTP verification for my Android device, and while everything works and I can receive the OTP, the browser reCAPTCHA occurs, and I am taken to the next stage in my app. This doesn't seem like a problem, but the inner code of "onVerificationCompleted" does not execute. In my app, the steps for "onCodeSent" run when it is auto-verified and I am redirected to the OTP filling page. So, a few data statuses are not changed.

Here is my code:

```java
PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;

mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

    @Override
    public void onVerificationCompleted(@NonNull PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
        // This callback will be invoked in two situations:
        // 1 - Instant verification. In some cases, the phone number can be instantly
        //     verified without needing to send or enter a verification code.
        // 2 - Auto-retrieval. On some devices, Google Play services can automatically
        //     detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without
        //     user action.

        user.updatePhoneNumber(credential).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                String userId = userID;
                Boolean verification = true;
                email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
                User user = new User(name, phone, email, usertype, userId, verification);
                UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(user_details_register.this, "Verification Complete. User Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(main);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                        UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user);
                    }
                });
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                user.updatePhoneNumber(credential);
                String userId = userID;
                Boolean verification = true;
                email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
                User user = new User(name, phone, email, usertype, userId, verification);
                UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(user_details_register.this, "Verification Complete. User Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(main);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                        UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user);
                    }
                });
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onVerificationFailed(@NonNull FirebaseException e) {
        // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,
        // for instance, if the phone number format is not valid.

        if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
            //Invalid number
            Toast.makeText(user_details_register.this, "Please check your number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
            String userId = userID;
            Boolean verification = false;
            email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
            User user = new User(name, phone, email, usertype, userId, verification);
            UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(user_details_register.this, "Verification could not be completed. Please try again later. User Data saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(main);
                    finish();
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                    UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user);
                }
            });
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;

        } else if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthMissingActivityForRecaptchaException) {
            // reCAPTCHA verification attempted with null Activity
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return;
        }

        // Show a message and update the UI
    }

    @Override
    public void onCodeSent(@NonNull String verificationId,
                           @NonNull PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
        // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
        // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
        // by combining the code with a verification ID.


        // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
        @NonNull String mVerificationId = verificationId;
        PhoneAuthProvider.@NonNull ForceResendingToken mResendToken = token;

        String userId = userID;
        Boolean verification = false;
        email = getIntent().getStringExtra("email");
        User user = new User(name, phone, email, usertype, userId, verification);
        UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                Toast.makeText(user_details_register.this, "OTP sent to your number: " + phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent otp_ver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtpVerification.class);
                otp_ver.putExtra("OTPBackend", verificationId);
                startActivity(otp_ver);
                finish();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@androidx.annotation.NonNull Exception e) {
                UserDB.child("Users").child(userID).setValue(user);
                Intent otp_ver = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OtpVerification.class);
                otp_ver.putExtra("number", phone);
                otp_ver.putExtra("OTPBackend", verificationId);
                startActivity(otp_ver);
                finish();
            }
        });
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
};

PhoneAuthOptions options =
        PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
                .setPhoneNumber("+91" + phone.trim())       // Phone number to verify
                .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Timeout and unit
                .setActivity(user_details_register.this)                 // (optional) Activity for callback binding
                // If no activity is passed, reCAPTCHA verification can not be used.
                .setCallbacks(mCallbacks)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                .build();

PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options);
```